# Boot entire Laravel5 application from outside

Tags: php, laravel, initialization, bootstrapping

I'm trying to boot entire L5 application from an external php script. I need to get access to Eloquent models and facades. For example, I have two installed and working applications in separate folders:

- /var/www/drupal7
- /var/www/drupal7/laravel

my nginx vhost config:

```
location /laravel {
      root   /var/www/drupal7/laravel/public;
      index index.php;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /laravel/public/index.php?$query_string;
}
```

my /var/www/drupal7/laravel/routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/laravel', function () {
    return 'Laravel';
});
```

Both applications works fine, but I need to boot laravel app from external script and I want to get access to models, views, configs. 
My question is - how can I do this properly?

I tried to achieve this using below code:

```
<?php

require '/var/www/drupal7/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    '/var/www/drupal7/laravel/'
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Http\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

use App\User;

$user = User::find(1);
var_dump($user);
```

but I get follow error message:

```
Error: Call to a member function connection() on null in Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::resolveConnection() (line 1013 of /var/www/drupal7/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php)
```

Comment: Take at look at the public/index.php to see how the framework boots itself for a request. Look at artisan.php to see how this happens from the command line.

Comment: If I use approach from these files I get follow error message:

`FatalErrorException in Router.php line 314:
Illuminate\Routing\Router::loadRoutes(): Failed opening required '/' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
// boot laravel
require __DIR__ .'/../../vendor/autoload.php';
$laravel_app = require __DIR__ .'/../../bootstrap/start.php';
$laravel_app->boot();
```

See [this article for the solution that helped me](https://www.jacopobeschi.com/post/integrate-laravel-session-in-external-php-application)